# spring data jpa native query pagination for SQLServer

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring 4.x and hibernate 5.x with SQLServer. I have a requirement to paginate data returned by a nativequery. I'm doing it like this:

```
@Query(value="select * from X where y=?1 \n#pageable\n",
            countQuery="select count(*) from X where y=?1 \n#pageable\n",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Object[]> XXX(Integer userId, Pageable pageable);
```

It's throwing me com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '#pageable'. If I don't use \n#pageable\n then it gives me compile time error that #pageable can't be used with native query. Please help if anyone faced similar issue

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?